# Java android room get HashMap grom db

Tags: java, android, android-room

This is my entity ;

```
public class LoadingRow {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderId")
    public long orderId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "binType")
    private String binType;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "trashType")
    private String trashType;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "count")
    private int count;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    private String status;
}
```

and this is my dao function

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM bin")
    Map<Long,List<LoadingRow>> getBinsMap();
```

And a problem is that I want to get a HAshMap

where a key is orderId and a list of Loadings is a list where all Loadings orderId is this same

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you're asking for is possible using Room. If I'm mistaken and it is possible, it should be pretty complicated.

You better off creating a query which gets all `LoadingRow` objects that have the same `orderId`, like so:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM bin WHERE orderId = :orderId")
List<LoadingRow> getRowsById(long orderId)
```

Then you can use this collection as needed, and insert it to a HashMap.